# WebView2 and Evergreen bootstrapper

Tags: webview2

I working on old application with wpf and winforms. It is deployed on Citrix servrar and users have Citrix Workspace to use the application.
We have begun to use webview2 in tries to do some more modern functions to the user. I'm an old web developer and have some problems with winforms and wpf.

I have tried to use fix version which I supplied in my release. It worked. But now I have read about Evergreen bootstraper and want to test it.
But I dont understand how I do this. Microsoft writes:

*Link to the bootstrapper, using a link that you obtain from the Get the Link button. Your app uses **this link to programmatically download the bootstrapper onto the client and invoke the bootstrapper**. This approach avoids the need to package the bootstrapper with your app. This approach has a dependency on Microsoft's Content Delivery Network (CDN), to get the bootstrapper*.

But where will I put this link to programmatically download the bootstrapper onto the client and invoke the bootstrapper ?

I suppose it is my bad knowledge about wpf/winforms platform, which is the problem. I have search a lot after examples when Evergreen will be implemented but haven't found anything

So, if some can explain for me how an Evergreen implementation will be done I would be happy!